# Rails: in_groups_of - error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out how to link to my articles in my view, and am getting stuck on the 'in_groups_of' call.

I have the following in a view partial:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <% Article.in_groups_of(2) do |group| %>
      <div class="row">
        <% group.compact.each do |article| %>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
              <div class="indexdisplay">
              <%= image_tag article.image_url, width: '100%', height: '200px' if article.image.present? %>
                  <div class="indexheading"> <%= link_to article.title, article %> </div>
                <div class="indexsubtext">    <%= truncate(article.body, :ommission => "...", :length => 250) %></div>
                 </div>
            </div>
              <% end %>
              </div>

    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

When I try and render it I get this error:

```
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `in_groups_of' for #<Class:0x007fa70300cda8>
```

Can anyone see what's wrong?

I tried changing Article to Articles (my model file is article.rb), but I then get this error:

```
NameError at /
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Articles
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <% Article.all.in_groups_of(2) do |group| %>
      <div class="row">
        <% group.compact.each do |article| %>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
              <div class="indexdisplay">
              <%= image_tag article.image_url, width: '100%', height: '200px' if article.image.present? %>
                  <div class="indexheading"> <%= link_to article.title, article %> </div>
                <div class="indexsubtext">    <%= truncate(article.body, :ommission => "...", :length => 250) %></div>
                 </div>
            </div>
              <% end %>
              </div>

    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks. I have to wait another 5 mins to accept this as correct